# Unity3D: Clicking on a specific regions of an object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a project for my university course. I want to create a globe with clickable cities (just a few) that will change the scene upon clicking. I've been following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QN39W020LqU, on how to create my own sphere. It uses a coordinate system. So far, I have only found tutorials on how to make an entire object clickable, but I want to make a certain region of an object clickable, possibly using the coordinates that were used in the tutorial I am using. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code. Otherwise you can use a `RaycastHit` and get the [point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) on the sphere.

Comment: As suggested by Hristo, either use the coordinates of the RaycastHit, or simply add invisible colliders (empty gameObject with a sphere collider + script) around your cities.